# converted to string database

Tags: php, database, string

) I wrote a method to display the contents of the database  public

```
function magazyn() {
        //return 'magazyn';
        $this->magazyn = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `products` ORDER BY `nazwa`");
        //$this->magazyn->bind_param('ssss', $id, $nazwa, $kategoria, $sn);
        $this->magazyn->execute();
        $this->magazyn->store_result();
        return $this->magazyn;

        if ($this->magazyn->num_rows > 0) {
            echo "jest cos w magazynie";
        } else {
            echo "Brak produktw w bazie";
        }
    }

    function __toString() {
        return $this->magazyn;
    }

$web = new Web();
echo $web->magazyn();
```

And in site i have error:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_stmt could not be
>   converted to string in...

Comment: The error says it all. `__toString` returns a string, but you're trying to return an object that can't be converted.

Comment: ___You___ have to write the code in the `__toString()` method that will convert `$destinationClub` to a string