# Convert data from database To string to use with Liphsoft.Crypto.Argon2, c#

Tags: c#

I had check that:[How convert dataset value in string in asp.net c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38563804/how-convert-dataset-value-in-string-in-asp-net-c-sharp)
and that, but it haven't my same error: [converted to string database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37114097/converted-to-string-database-)
I'm trying to cast a data from database to a string-
when I tryed the first link, it says:"No row at position 0"
(if(true) the label change content)

```
 MySqlCommand sqlpsw = new MySqlCommand("Select password from user where email='" + _email + "'", conn);
 sqlpsw.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
 MySqlDataAdapter pswadapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
 pswadapter.SelectCommand = sqlpsw;
 DataSet pswdataSet = new DataSet();
 pswadapter.Fill(pswdataSet);
 var hasher = new PasswordHasher();
        if (hasher.Verify(pswdataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["column name"].ToString(), "password_value"))
            {
            label.Content = "ok";
        }else
        {
            label.Content = "ko";
        }
```

trying to change it with `if (hasher.Verify(pswdataSet.ToString(), "password_value"))` it does not give any error, but if I try tu put pswdataSet.ToString() into label.Content, it show:"System.Data.DataSet"
Have you got any ideas how fix that?

Comment: new DataSet makes the row count in all tables -1 until columns are added then row count goes to zero.

Comment: And making .tables[+/-1] can't fix that I think

Comment: When the table constructor is called the rows count is set to -1.  Then when first column is added the row count goes to zero.  Row count does not go up until rows are added.